# Error in my typescript file in react project

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image: first half of the image]

[image: second half of the image]

I've cloned a typescript file and added in my react  project in create-react-app and it's showing a lot errors in the return function. I guess all the errors are rooted to one common mistake. Anyone can please help me find out?

here is the code of the file:

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "./Component7.module.scss";
import  './component7.scss';

const Component7 = ({
  janeDoe = "Jane Doe",
  student = "Student",
  details = "DETAILS",
  username = "Username :",
  emailAddress = "Email address :",
  password = "Password :",
  dateOfBirth = "Date of birth :",
  thunderBalance = "Thunder Balance :",
  num600 = "600",
  editDetails = "Edit Details"
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.component7}>
      <p className={classes.janeDoe}>{janeDoe}</p>
      <p className={classes.student}>{student}</p>
      <img
        alt=""
        className={classes.vector5}
        src="https://static.overlay-tech.com/assets/aa911a93-6f68-4cde-9fd6-ce8d7d43529d.svg"
      />
      <p className={classes.details}>{details}</p>
      <p className={classes.username}>{username}</p>
      <p className={classes.emailAddress}>{emailAddress}</p>
      <p className={classes.username}>{password}</p>
      <p className={classes.dateOfBirth}>{dateOfBirth}</p>
      <div className={classes.flexWrapperTwo}>
        <p className={classes.thunderBalance}>
          {thunderBalance}
        </p>
        <p className={classes.num600}>{num600}</p>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.flexWrapperOne}>
        <p className={classes.editDetails}>{editDetails}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component7;
```

I've also attached the snapshot of the vs code for the error visuals

Answer (score 0):

Is your file extension is `tsx` (or `jsx`)?